# How to tell if a switch is on a GFCI branch circuit

Tags: electrical, gfci, exhaust-fan

I am looking to install [this light/exhaust fan combo](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Broan-1-5-Sone-70-CFM-White-Lighted-Bathroom-Fan/1242821) over a shower and see that it's approved for such use "with a GFCI branch circuit."  It is on the same circuit as a GFCI receptacle, so my understanding is that if it comes after that receptacle, it fits that requirement.  Am I correct, and how could I confirm that it's after the GFCI receptacle on the circuit?  Thanks!

Comment: @crip659 's comment is the answer. FYI, that particular light/fan seems to be a relatively poor choice to me - you generally want to look for higher CFM = better fan, lower Sone = less noise. Based on various others on the same page, you may be able to find better options pretty easily for similar price. But the GFCI issue will be the same with all of them.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact thanks a bunch!  I chose that fan bc it was in stock, had great reviews, and seemed easy to install in my drop ceiling situation, since it has the metal extension bars.  wish i had more bandwidth to really figure out what's best but that's not my situation unfortunately (-:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a cable/wire in conduit/light already there, then there should not be power if you use the test button on the GFCI receptacle.

GFCI receptacles have line screws and load screws.  If both wires are on the line set, then no protection past that point.

If the light wires are on the load set, then GFCI protection.

Can change the light/fan wires to the load side after turning off the breaker, if needed.

It is also possible that that circuit is on another circuit than the GFCI receptacle, which makes life more difficult.  Might need to add a GFCI breaker to the panel, if the light circuit is not protected by GFCI.

Comment: thank you!  they should be on the same circuit bc they both go dead when i switch that breaker, so sounds like i just need to put the light wires on the load screws! (currently, pressing the test button does not kill the light unfortunately)